# Not able to apply css to the asp.net mvc login page where it says refuse to apply inline css,

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

Not able to apply css to the asp.net mvc login page. chrome browser says

'Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-PyLHmjCk4/4GwQUxB5Nv2ZOIHPu1XXusXCu09QBy+nc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDvD1.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the error message that you have an inline style, which CSP blocks. You can put that style in your CSS file instead.

You can also use `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';` in your `content-security-policy` declaration, but this is not recommended for security concern.

Check this [OWASP explanation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-4-css-encode-and-strictly-validate-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-html-style-property-values) for more details.